# Select case with multiple columns along with other columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following tables

**ID_TYPE**

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

**ID_HISTORY**

| DEBIT_ID | DEBIT_LOCATION | AMOUNT | CREDIT_ID | CREDIT_LOCATION | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | LOC1 | 100 | 1 | LOC5 | MAY |
| 4 | LOC2 | 200 | 3 | LOC6 | MAY |
| 2 | LOC3 | 300 | 5 | LOC7 | MAY |
| 1 | LOC4 | 400 | 3 | LOC8 | JUNE |
| 3 | LOC9 | 500 | 2 | LOC10 | JUNE |

Now suppose I want to fetch all rows from ID_HISTORY in the MONTH of MAY, and result should contain only these columns:

```
Id, Location, Amount
```

**Cases:**

- Result should contain rows only where either `DEBIT_ID` or `CREDIT_ID` is of `TYPE`=3 in `ID_TYPE` table
- If the `DEBIT_ID` is of `TYPE` = 3 in the `ID_TYPE` table, then pick `DEBIT_ID` as "Id", else pick `CREDIT_ID` as "Id"
- Similarly, If the `DEBIT_ID` is of `TYPE` 3 in the `ID_TYPE` table, then pick `DEBIT_LOCATION` as "Location", else pick `CREDIT_LOCATION` as "Location"

For example, above tables should result in the following:

| Id | Location | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LOC5 | 100 |
| 2 | LOC3 | 300 |

I know that something like the following should work:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN (Tab.DEBIT_ID IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM ID_TYPE Typ
            WHERE Typ.TYPE = 3)
            ) THEN Tab.DEBIT_ID
        ELSE Tab.CREDIT_ID END
        )                           "Id",
    (CASE
        WHEN (Tab.DEBIT_ID IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM ID_TYPE Typ
            WHERE Typ.TYPE = 3)
            ) THEN Tab.DEBIT_LOCATION
        ELSE Tab.CREDIT_LOCATION END
        )                           "Location",
    Tab.AMOUNT                      "Amount"
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM ID_HISTORY Tab
    WHERE Tab.MONTH = 'MAY'
    --this block will be very complicated and contain complex multi-level queries to fetch data
)
```

But as you can see this will be inefficient as I have to basically duplicate the full case logic for each conditional columns. Also, this is no way "clean" in case there are a lot of similar columns.

Also, if the case logic is complex, it will be inefficient even further. It would be better if i could select multiple columns in `THEN` / `ELSE` cases. I tried doing that, but it just gives me "ORA-00913: too many values" error.

What would be the optimized version?

Comment: Why does your output show only two rows? What happened to the row where amount = 200?

Comment: @mathguy - because on that row, none of the credit_id or debit_id has `type` = 3 in ID_TYPE table

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, you look up the debit id and the credit id in the "type" table, and look to see if the corresponding type is 3. Fine - I understand now why the row where amount = 200 is not selected. But then, why is the last row (with amount = 500) not selected? It has credit id = 2, which is of type 3 in the lookup table.

Comment: @mathguy Because as i mentioned, result should be `in the MONTH of MAY`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join to remove the sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN typ.id IS NOT NULL
       THEN h.debit_id
       ELSE h.credit_id
       END AS id,
       CASE
       WHEN typ.id IS NOT NULL
       THEN h.debit_location
       ELSE h.credit_location
       END AS location,
       h.AMOUNT
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM   ID_HISTORY
       WHERE  MONTH = 'MAY'
       -- this block will be very complicated and contain complex multi-level queries to fetch data
     ) h
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
       SELECT id
       FROM   id_type
       WHERE  type = 3
     ) typ
     ON (h.debit_id = typ.id)
```

Comment: While this is better, I was hoping if there was a way to do something like 
`WHEN typ.id IS NOT NULL THEN h.debit_id as id, h.debit_location as location ELSE h.credit_id as id, h.credit_location as location END`